# Windows Server: some services don't start at boot

Tags: windows-server-2008, boot, service

I have a Windows Server 2008 which is not booting in the right way anymore. Over 20 services aren't loaded when Windows is booting. I've installed some server tools like MS Sql Server, MySql etc.

I assume that at least one service causes an error message when Windows is booting. Because this is a vServer I have no direct access to the machine. The only tool I have is Parallels Power Panel. Unfortunately I am not able to start the RDP service.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is go to the services section and verify they're set to start automatically, Second thing I would do is check the event viewer and see what it has to say. Your logs should give you some idea of what's going on.

Comment: Hey Richard, okay the services are set to start automatically. Can I get event messages from the file system? I am not able to get a remote connection.

Comment: @Mark: If you're not able to RDP the machine, you may still be able to use a local `eventvwr` to connect to the remote computer's event logs.

Comment: 10 bucks says rpc is in a failed condition thus eventvwr won't work remotely either! so wth parallels you can't get local console? That will be real painful if rpc is not working...

Comment: I tried to connect via eventvwr, but it says there is no rpc server. Could it be possible that one service causes a message box at startup?

Comment: Can you start the rpc service? or as tony asked, is Parallels able to give you a local console?

Answer (score 0):

How about starting off with a chkdsk to address any possible disk/volume stations first? You should be able to mount the volume on a functioning VM, if needed to accomplish the chkdsk.

Comment: If he's on a virtualization platform, there is little chance that the VM has physical disk access, so chkdsk won't do a whole lot.

Comment: Actually, the chkdsk in the VM will check out the VM disk structure which acts exactly like a physical volume and can also suffer damage (hint: file/volume damage).

Comment: We're still trying to figure out if he can get a "local console"

Comment: @user - It will check for file-level corruption, but unless there was some sort of power outage, file-level corruption without physical disk damage is rather rare. The full benefit of chkdsk is from the /r switch which will look for bad sectors and recover data if possible.

Comment: Or unclean reboots/restarts/resets... Why do you seem to not like to check your system for file/structure errors when it is actually more common than given credit for?